# Waiting time in queue for different types of agents coming from one source and getting served in one service in Anylogic

Tags: java, function, collections, anylogic

I want to find waiting time of each patient type (agent type) coming from one source and getting served by one machine. I have classified patient types using schedule block and function as shown in photo1[function body for classifying agent types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQVV.png), and now I wish to calculate mean waiting time of each patient type(1-6) in queue of one service block. As of now there are 4 patients scheduled of each type in every two hours ( simulation is run for 12 hours).
Thanks

I'm not sure whether timeMeasureStart and End blocks will be of some use here.
Data and Statistics block (model in photo2[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVJUU.png)) are giving mean waiting time of all the patients and not for each patient type.
I'm struggling from quite some time now, and tried to use function and collection also for the same, but didn't got anything. Any hint or suggestion to solve this will be of great help.

Comment: If you've explored your functions and collections, I'd suggest saving the start time of an agent's process duration in a variable within the agent. Then, when the agent exits the process, save the duration within (you can get the current time by calling time(), then just compute the difference) a separate collection/statistics/object of your choice for each agent type. Otherwise, you can do as Benjamin suggested below.

Comment: I did this in the service block, but that gives the average waiting time of all the agent types; please can you suggest how to find it for each patient type (1-6)?

Comment: As previously mentioned, you should save each patient type's waiting time in a separate collection object. The way you do this is up to you but I'd assume you have a parameter determining each agent's type - just sort them into their respective collection object according to that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are a beginner. In that case, I'd suggest that you use the "Select output 5" object before the queue and route your patients through different flows, each with its own queue and "time measure" blocks.

This way you have full control. You can route your agents in the "select output 5" block using 'agent.myPatientType' (or similar) so that they join the right flow (check the help and example models for this)

However, it is also the least elegant choice

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I've not used Anylogic much, but I want to get along with functions and collections or any objects that reduces redundant work/ blocks in the model. I'll once try your suggestion, but it would be helpful, if you also suggest any other way of doing the same. 
Thank you.

Comment: The others would be a lot more advanced and probably overwhelm you for now, tbh :) (AnyLogic is a deep well :D )